# Java variables that prone to be collected by garbage collector

Tags: java, variables, garbage-collection

I don't exactly remember but there was an article for Java that explains variable modifiers that makes them prone to be collected by garbage collector. Is there any mechanism for Java to define variables as stepped to be collecting by garbage collector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for might be Weak Reference, have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference

Answer (score 0):

If an object is referenced (directly or indirectly) by a variable, it won't be collected at all.

Apart from that, there is nothing. Garbage collector is a black box and just does what it fits (even System.gc() is only a suggestion to run the garbage collection).

Answer (score 0):

I think you were referring to the [finalize](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29) keyword. Do take note that this only makes the suggestion to the compiler. The compiler may choose not to garbage collect. Or perhaps you were referring to weak references...

Answer (score 0):

No, except for the [weak reference api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html).